# Sign in with Mongo shell without having password shown?

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication

How can I sign into the Mongo shell without showing my password? Everything says to either use

```
mongo -u user -p password -authenticationDatabase admin
```

or

```
mongo
> use admin;
> db.auth('user', 'password')
```

I don't like either one. The first leaves a command in cmd's history. The second isn't in the history but it still displays on screen in plain text. I tried only specifying a user in hopes I'd get a password prompt that doesn't display characters as I type, but in both cases an error occurs.

Is there a way to sign into Mongo in a way that doesn't put my password on the screen or store it in an insecure file (like a .bat or anything)?

I'm operating in Windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add a flag `-p` but you don't specify a password, MongoDB shell will prompt you for a password.

```
mongo -u user -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

The password will be hidden as you type and will not be recorded in the shell history.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn if you're connecting with the use that has userAdminAnyDatabase role the auth db should be admin.

Comment: Yeah, but I still have to specify it. That's a lot of typing.

Comment: I guess if I run `mongo admin -u user -p` it's a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

`mongo admin -u admin -p` works (with the least typing), as noted by Corey.
The 1st "admin" is the database, and the 2nd "admin" is the user.